# Prestashop not possible to rename a category

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

Hei.
I have a problem with a page that is using prestashop 1.3.
Anyways i can't rename a category. I have alredy tried several methods but none have worked, so i hope someone has the solution to this problem.

This is what i have tried:
-Changed the name of the category in the CMS back end. (No effect, name on the page is still the same),
-Changed the name in the database, ps_category_language (No effect, name on the page is still the same),
-Manually deleted the cache files and the compile files in the domain/tools/smarty (No effect, name on the page is still the same),
-Disabling and enabling the whole page (No effect, name on the page is still the same),
-And changed in the smarty.config.inc.php file
from:

```
$smarty->caching        = true;
$smarty->force_compile  = false;
```

to:

```
$smarty->caching        = false;
$smarty->force_compile  = true;
```

but still the category's name did not change.

Does anyone have some idea what else could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After some other programmer change the name of the category with ease i wondered how is that possible.
I checked every single file on the server, he did none internal changes. Then i chacked the databes, all entrys, table by table, colum by colum.

Since this did not bring up any results i checked all the modules in the Back end. I found a strange, old module that was not connected to the database. So this module is a dead, on-site, static module with witch it's possible to change the name of the category.